# View page displays "Page not found" error but previously worked

Tags: 6, views, caching

I am working on a site at the moment with a View of "properties".  The view used to function perfectly but for some reason now displays a "Page not found" error when trying to access the page and during the Views AJAX preview, displays a 404 error when it tries to render. This has only started to happen in the last couple of days.

I've tried clearing all caches (inc Views cache), rebuilding permissions and deleting the View and importing it again but nothing seems to work.  It only happens with this particular View, all others on the site function correctly.

The exported View is shown below.  The version of views is 2.1.2.

Edit for new information:

- There is no menu entry assigned in the View but there is a menu item in the Primary Links. There are no particular access rules for the it either, everyone is allowed to access every View
- Menu has been rebuilt and all caches flushed and rebuilt
- I had it briefly working by disabling the Boost module.  I had a warning that Boost's .htaccess file was not properly configured, so I reconfigured the .htaccess file and I then enabled the module again that didn't work.  I then disabled Boost again, but it still didn't work, even after restoring Drupal's default .htaccess file.

-

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'properties_listing_2';
$view->description = 'Properties Listing 2';
$view->tag = '';
$view->view_php = '';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;
$view->api_version = 2;
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'field_property_image_fid' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '<br /><br /><br />No image available',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 1,
    'label_type' => 'none',
    'format' => 'property-page-image_linked',
    'multiple' => array(
      'group' => 1,
      'multiple_number' => '1',
      'multiple_from' => '0',
      'multiple_reversed' => 0,
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_property_image_fid',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_property_image',
    'field' => 'field_property_image_fid',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'title' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 1,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'title',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'title',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_price_value' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 1,
      'text' => '[field_price_value] pm',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'none',
    'format' => 'default',
    'multiple' => array(
      'group' => TRUE,
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_reversed' => FALSE,
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_price_value',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_price',
    'field' => 'field_price_value',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'body' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 1,
      'max_length' => '190',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 1,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'body',
    'table' => 'node_revisions',
    'field' => 'body',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_number_bedrooms_value' => array(
    'label' => 'Beds',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'custom',
    'format' => 'default',
    'multiple' => array(
      'group' => TRUE,
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_reversed' => FALSE,
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_number_bedrooms_value',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_number_bedrooms',
    'field' => 'field_number_bedrooms_value',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_available_date_value' => array(
    'label' => 'Available',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'custom',
    'format' => 'short',
    'multiple' => array(
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_to' => '',
      'group' => '',
    ),
    'repeat' => array(
      'show_repeat_rule' => '',
    ),
    'fromto' => array(
      'fromto' => 'both',
    ),
    'exclude' => 1,
    'id' => 'field_available_date_value',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_available_date',
    'field' => 'field_available_date_value',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'phpcode' => array(
    'label' => 'Available',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'value' => '<?php

print(date(\'jS M Y\', strtotime($data->node_data_field_price_field_available_date_value)));

?>',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'phpcode',
    'table' => 'customfield',
    'field' => 'phpcode',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_furnishing_value' => array(
    'label' => 'Furnished',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'custom',
    'format' => 'default',
    'multiple' => array(
      'group' => TRUE,
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_reversed' => FALSE,
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_furnishing_value',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_furnishing',
    'field' => 'field_furnishing_value',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_property_type_value' => array(
    'label' => 'Property Type',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'widget',
    'format' => 'default',
    'multiple' => array(
      'group' => TRUE,
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_reversed' => FALSE,
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_property_type_value',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_property_type',
    'field' => 'field_property_type_value',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_location_nid' => array(
    'label' => 'Locale',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'custom',
    'format' => 'plain',
    'multiple' => array(
      'group' => TRUE,
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_reversed' => FALSE,
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_location_nid',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_location',
    'field' => 'field_location_nid',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'view_node' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'text' => 'More details',
    'exclude' => 1,
    'id' => 'view_node',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'view_node',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'nid' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'exclude' => 1,
    'id' => 'nid',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'nid',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'nothing' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'text' => '[view_node]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.dominoletting.co.uk/printmail/[nid]">Email to friend</a>',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'nothing',
    'table' => 'views',
    'field' => 'nothing',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'type' => array(
    'operator' => 'in',
    'value' => array(
      'property' => 'property',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'type',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'type',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'status' => array(
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => '1',
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'status',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'status',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_general_location_value_many_to_one' => array(
    'operator' => 'or',
    'value' => array(),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => TRUE,
    'expose' => array(
      'use_operator' => 0,
      'operator' => 'field_general_location_value_many_to_one_op',
      'identifier' => 'general_location',
      'label' => 'Location',
      'optional' => 1,
      'single' => 1,
      'remember' => 0,
      'reduce' => 0,
    ),
    'id' => 'field_general_location_value_many_to_one',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_general_location',
    'field' => 'field_general_location_value_many_to_one',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'reduce_duplicates' => 0,
  ),
  'distance' => array(
    'operator' => 'dist',
    'value' => array(
      'latitude' => '',
      'longitude' => '',
      'postal_code' => '',
      'country' => 'uk',
      'php_code' => '',
      'nid_arg' => '',
      'nid_loc_field' => 'field_postcode_location',
      'uid_arg' => '',
      'search_distance' => '',
      'search_units' => 'mile',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => TRUE,
    'expose' => array(
      'use_operator' => 0,
      'operator' => 'distance_op',
      'identifier' => 'distance',
      'label' => '',
      'user_location_choose' => 0,
      'optional' => 1,
      'remember' => 0,
    ),
    'identifier' => 'dist',
    'origin' => 'postal_default',
    'id' => 'distance',
    'table' => 'location',
    'field' => 'distance',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'gmap_macro' => '',
  ),
  'field_property_type_value_many_to_one' => array(
    'operator' => 'or',
    'value' => array(),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => TRUE,
    'expose' => array(
      'use_operator' => 0,
      'operator' => 'field_property_type_value_many_to_one_op',
      'identifier' => 'property_type',
      'label' => 'Property Type',
      'optional' => 1,
      'single' => 1,
      'remember' => 0,
      'reduce' => 0,
    ),
    'id' => 'field_property_type_value_many_to_one',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_property_type',
    'field' => 'field_property_type_value_many_to_one',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'reduce_duplicates' => 0,
  ),
  'field_furnishing_value_many_to_one' => array(
    'operator' => 'or',
    'value' => array(),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => TRUE,
    'expose' => array(
      'use_operator' => 0,
      'operator' => 'field_furnishing_value_many_to_one_op',
      'identifier' => 'furnishing',
      'label' => 'Furnishing',
      'optional' => 1,
      'single' => 1,
      'remember' => 0,
      'reduce' => 0,
    ),
    'id' => 'field_furnishing_value_many_to_one',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_furnishing',
    'field' => 'field_furnishing_value_many_to_one',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'reduce_duplicates' => 0,
  ),
  'field_number_bedrooms_value' => array(
    'operator' => '>=',
    'value' => array(
      'value' => '',
      'min' => '',
      'max' => '',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => TRUE,
    'expose' => array(
      'use_operator' => 0,
      'operator' => 'field_number_bedrooms_value_op',
      'identifier' => 'min_bedrooms',
      'label' => 'Min. Bedrooms',
      'optional' => 1,
      'remember' => 0,
    ),
    'id' => 'field_number_bedrooms_value',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_number_bedrooms',
    'field' => 'field_number_bedrooms_value',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_price_value' => array(
    'operator' => '>=',
    'value' => array(
      'value' => '',
      'min' => '',
      'max' => '',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => TRUE,
    'expose' => array(
      'use_operator' => 0,
      'operator' => 'field_price_value_op',
      'identifier' => 'min_price',
      'label' => 'Min. Price',
      'optional' => 1,
      'remember' => 0,
    ),
    'id' => 'field_price_value',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_price',
    'field' => 'field_price_value',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_price_value_1' => array(
    'operator' => '<=',
    'value' => array(
      'value' => '',
      'min' => '',
      'max' => '',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => TRUE,
    'expose' => array(
      'use_operator' => 0,
      'operator' => 'field_price_value_1_op',
      'identifier' => 'max_price',
      'label' => 'Max. Price (£ Monthly)',
      'optional' => 1,
      'remember' => 0,
    ),
    'id' => 'field_price_value_1',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_price',
    'field' => 'field_price_value',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('access', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('cache', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('title', 'Property Search');
$handler->override_option('empty', 'No results available.  Please refine your search.');
$handler->override_option('empty_format', '1');
$handler->override_option('use_pager', '1');
$handler->override_option('exposed_block', TRUE);
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Property Search Original', 'page_1');
$handler->override_option('path', 'properties');
$handler->override_option('menu', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
$handler->override_option('tab_options', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Property Search Table', 'page_2');
$handler->override_option('path', 'properties2');
$handler->override_option('menu', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
$handler->override_option('tab_options', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
```

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot or description of 1) the menu-settings of the view (page) and 2) any insights on how you have the access of the view configured?

Comment: There is no menu entry assigned in the View but there is a menu item in the Primary Links.  There are no particular access rules for the it either, everyone is allowed to access every View.

Comment: have you tried to rebuild the menu?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and emptied all caches, but nothing.

Comment: Does the path exist in the menu_router table in the database?

Comment: I would suggest you start by removing and disabling (entirely!) as many modules as possible. Starting with Boost. Reading through your comments it seems the problem is not in views, but in some module misbehaving with your views(settings) or a views-addon.

Comment: And start with removing Calendar module if you're using it - I remember seeing some issues with Views 2.x + Calendar, don't recall the details though.

Also, do a quick health check of your view, for example make sure you're not using any non-existent fields anywhere (does anything has changed recently?)

You could try to create a new view exactly like this one and monitor on each step whether it still works or not.

Comment: Did you try cloning the page view display, creating a different URL, then typing that URL directly into your browser?

Comment: Go to devel/php, and do a dpm(menu_get_item('properties')); and see what comes up. You should be able to see the page callback to give you an idea of what is handling the URL.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, but I don't have boost enabled on this site. Cleared all caches, there's an entry in the menu_router table, tried cloning the view to a new path, still doesn't work. The fact that it was working fine and then suddenly stopped without warning is worrying, the fact that I had this happen on another site is just scary...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change the view path to something else ?

Did you try *"To clear Boosts cache set "Ignore cache flushing:" to 'Disabled' in the boost advanced settings & try again."* ?

Does your hosting support gzip compression ?

As far as I know there is Boost option "Aggressive Gzip: Deliver gzipped content independent of the request header". What happens if you uncheck the "Aggressive Gzip" option under the Boost Configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, long shot, maybe you are using Pathauto and somehow the URL you used got nuked?  That's happened to me a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have the same issue as me. The problem for me was caused by using the imagecache preset linked to the node and by ticking the views "link this field to its node".

The view was working perfectly up until a few hours ago and also worked perfectly when I created a dump of the database and imported the site work on it locally. This suggests to me that there's something super obscure going on with the server (shared hosting) setup.

In your case, for your field "field_property_image_fid" you can't have link_to_node = 1 at the same time as using the property-page-image_linked format.

If this fixes the problem for you, and my solution wasn't something just specific to my setup, could you please open an issue in the queue on the Views' project page?

Comment: nm, issue is here - http://drupal.org/node/1422634

Answer (score 0):

In my case disabling the `/taxonomy/term/` view fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this, think it must be php version related maybe.it turned out to be the "field_property_image_fid" in the view for me as it was for David. Was the image from a ubercart product.

Deleted (it wasn't even needed in the view!) it and all was ok again.

Thanks.