# How to debug weird "page not found" after creating a view?

Tags: 7

I'm having a really weird problem with my site on my localhost. It might be similar to this [issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10932/view-page-displays-page-not-found-error-but-previously-worked).

I had setup the site just a few weeks ago had started to migrate user and node records using the migrate module. I created a view to show user records and pushed it to my development site (using Pantheon).

Today I tried to import a view from another site and after saving it it show "page not found). I tried to recreate the view manually with the same result. Even when I create the most basic view (top 10 nodes or top 10 users) I get a "page not found" error.
The view doesn't show up in the menu_router table.

The site was 7.10 or 7.11 when I created it and had upgraded to 7.12 using the Pantheon tool. I'm using the MAMP software for months now and haven't made any setup changes. They also did an update to bootstrap.inc but I don't know what they changed.

I don't have the issue on my dev site and my code base on local is the same. I went from views 7.x.3.1 back to 7.x.3-rc3 but that didn't fix it.

The one thing that looks strange to me is the path in the "page not found error message:

> The requested page "/mt/test6" could not be found.

The page is at http://localhost:8888/mt/test6

shouldn't the error just say "test6 could not be found?
I had played with the $base_url in settings.php a few days ago but had removed it again.

Any ideas what I could do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: after disabling the "menu" menu and re-enabling it again everything worked again. I hope I don't run into more weird issues like this.

Comment: Your domain is 'localhost' and will always cause a 404 if not connected to locally.  Can this be ruled out?